# Node Fetch resolve host like curl request

Tags: node.js, node-fetch, node-http-proxy, node-https

can we replicate curl resolve host in node-fetch or any other node http library.

`curl https://www.example.net --resolve www.example.net:443:127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need another lib to do this. The builtin http module works fine:

```js
const http = require('http');

const options = {
  hostname: '2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946',
  port: 80,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Host': 'example.com'
  }
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});

req.end();
```

In HTTP protocol, the host name is in headers, and the IP used to establish the TCP connection is independent from that.

Comment: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: ''
  port: 80
}
Its giving this error

Comment: your server is https, please `require('https')` and connect to 443 port (by default), refer to https://nodejs.org/api/https.html